# unable to reach java class files when deployed in Testing server

Tags: java, tomcat, web-deployment

I'm using tomcat server v.6 in development, testing and production phase. My web application implementing blazeDS in tomcat server works fine in development environment. I use csv file as flat database, the file is located in my application directory of tomcat webapps folder. I get connected to this flat file by retrieving the path using

```
 ServletContext sc = config.getServletContext();
 String App_path = sc.getRealPath("/");
```

The problem arises when i deploy it in testing server. I dont know what went wrong, the application doesn't fetch records from the flat file. I even tried to print the path to connect csv file using MessageDialog box, but it returned nothing.

Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

we need more help - like a log file or something.

might be a security issue, like the test server file system not giving access to the user running the app?

try something like

System.out.println(new File(App_path).getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(new File(App_path).exists());

and other java.io.File methods which you can use to check the existance and readability of the file.  once you post more info, we might be able to help more.

Comment: Hi, I fixed the bug. It actually didn't compile the jsp file that posted error message in localhost Log file. Cleared the bug and deployed it in testing server. It works fine.